# If $A\subset B$, $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $A$, $x+\mathfrak{p}B$ is a unit, irreducible $f\in A[X]$ has $f(x)=0$, must $[X^0]f\notin\mathfrak{p}$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, $B$ be an integral extension of $A$ (that is, every element in $B$ is a root of a monic polynomial in $A[X]$). Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Suppose that $x\in B$, and that $x+\mathfrak{p}B$ is a unit in the ring $B/\mathfrak{p}B$ ($\mathfrak{p}B$ is the ideal of $B$ generated by $\mathfrak{p}$). If a polynomial $f(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1X + a_0\in A[X]$, irreducible over $A[X]$ has $f(x)=0$, must we have $a_0\notin \mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: Can you take $B = \mathbb{Q}$ and $A = \mathbb{Z}$ as a counterexample? For example $\mathfrak{p} = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(X) = X - 2$ and $x = 2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, $f(2) = 0$ and $2 + (2) \cdot \mathbb{Q}$ is a unit in the zero ring $\mathbb{Q}/ 2 \mathbb{Q}$, but $a_0 = 2 \in \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @MatyMangoo: Yes you are right! I've edited the question, requiring $B$ to be integral over $A$.

Comment: If $B/A$ is integral then yes because $A[x]/\mathfrak{p}$ is a subring of $B/\mathfrak{p}$. Replacing $A$ by $A_\mathfrak{p}$ you can assume that $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal. So $f\bmod \mathfrak{p}$ is the minimal polynomial of $x\bmod \mathfrak{p}$ and being a unit its determinant, ie. $f(0)$, is non-zero ($\bmod \mathfrak{p}$)

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your answer, but I would like to ask that why $f \text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$ is the minimal polynomial of $x\text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$, i.e., why is $f \text{ mod }\mathfrak{p}$ irreducible?